# Character Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, character

So, what I am trying to do is encription so the steps would be:

Read in a 4-letter word.

Parse the String into chars and convert the chars to ints. Store these decimal values in an array.

Multiply by your encryption matrix

Print the encoded word.

Multiply by the inverse of the encryption matrix and print out it out

But, the step I am having trouble on is printing the encoded word.  At the very bottom where I am printing the word nothing shows up.  Is there something that I am doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String [] args){

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String word = "give"; {

    while(word.length() == 4){
        word=word;}

    while(word.length() != 4){
        word=input.next();
        }


    int[][] wordArray =  new int[2][2];
    wordArray[0][0] = (int)word.charAt(1);
    wordArray[0][1] = (int)word.charAt(2);
    wordArray[1][0] = (int)word.charAt(3);
    wordArray[1][1] = (int)word.charAt(4);

    int[][] encriptionArray = new int [2][2];
    encriptionArray[0][0] =  1;
    encriptionArray[0][1] = 2;
    encriptionArray[1][0] = 3;
    encriptionArray[1][1] = (4);


    int[][] printArray = new int [2][2];
    printArray[0][0]= wordArray[0][0]*encriptionArray[0][0]+ wordArray[0][1]*encriptionArray[0][1];
    printArray[0][1]= wordArray[0][1]*encriptionArray[0][1]+ wordArray[0][1]*encriptionArray[1][1];
    printArray[1][0]= wordArray[1][0]*encriptionArray[0][0]+ wordArray[1][1]*encriptionArray[1][0];
    printArray[1][1]= wordArray[0][1]*encriptionArray[1][0]+ wordArray[1][1]*encriptionArray[0][1];

    System.out.print(printArray[0][0]);
    System.out.print(printArray[0][1]);
    System.out.print(printArray[1][0]);
    System.out.print(printArray[1][1]);

}


}
```

}

Comment: is there something wrong with my question?

Answer (score 0):

```
String word = "give";

while(word.length() == 4){
    word=word;
}
```

That is an infinite loop. `word = word;` does nothing. And since word has a length of 4, the while loop executes continuously. Learn to use your debugger, and execute your code line by line to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Change your while loop to something like this:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter 4-letter word:");
    word = input.nextLine();
    if(word.length()==4){
        break;
    }
}
```